# Protect my passwords in Passwords and Keys program

Tags: keyrings

I just found out that I can see all of my passwords in **Passwords and Keys** program. That means any friend of mine can see my passwords if he/she uses my computer for some temporary use.

I know I can lock it and unlock it by entering password

How to I keep it locked until I enter password, and **lock it again automatically after that one time use**?

**People should read the bold part above**

Comment: see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/seahorse/+bug/189774

Comment: @pl_rock your link does not solve my question, please read the bold part

Comment: @edwardtorvalds: What you want is covered by the answers to the linked question. Unfortunately the answer is: this is currently impossible; a bug has been filed.

Comment: @DavidFoerster you should put this comment in answer :) thanks btw